# Python pandas misses some end of line characters while loading csv file

Tags: python, pandas, file-processing

I have a csv file (tab seperated) written in German. I did not create the file. I tried to read that file by using Python's pandas package. I do the following:

```
import pandas as pd
trn_file ="data/train.csv"
pd_train = pd.read_csv(trn_file,delimiter='\t',encoding='utf-8',header=None)
# pd_train is [1153 rows x 12 columns]
# the first  couple of rows of pd_train can be seen below:
>>> pd_train
        0                                                  1                                     2    3           4   5   6                                                7                                                8                      9     10    11
0       35  Auch in Großbritannien, wo 19 Atomreaktoren in...                              Ausstieg -1.0  2011-03-13  10  10                                     Sunday Times                                     Sunday Times           Sunday Times   NaN     1
1      117  Deswegen sollte Deutschland nicht für [...] we...                              Ausstieg  1.0  2011-04-11  60  62                                 Dietram Hoffmann                                 Dietram Hoffmann                    NaN   NaN   121
```

When I investigate the dataframe, I realized that the file does not properly parsed. I mean, I see lines that seems merged even though there is a newline character between them. For example the example below shows a sentence but actually it contains 4 sentences. (They should have been in seperate rows in the dataframe):

```
>>> pd_train[1][483]
'Wer keine Brücke will, kann auch keine Brückenmaut verlangen. Eine Klage gegen die Kernbrennstoffsteuer schließe ich nicht aus.\tKonsens/Einigkeit\t-1.0\t2011-05-03\t90\t91\tEon\tJohannes Teyssen\tEon\t\t558\n3\tEin solches schicksalhaftes Langzeitprojekt ist für einen kurzsichtigen Profilierungswettstreit der Parteien ungeeignet. Deshalb müssen wir einen Konsens finden, der von einer breiten Mehrheit auf Dauer getragen wird.\tKonsens/Einigkeit\t1.0\t2011-05-10\t50\t55\tAlois Glück\tAlois Glück\tZentralkomitee der Katholiken\t31.0\t576\n1459\tWir brauchen jetzt keine Kommissionen, sondern einen neuen, breiten Konsens, der dann wirklich hält.\tKonsens/Einigkeit\t1.0\t2011-04-12\t30\t30\tClaudia Roth\tClaudia Roth\tGrüne\t34.0\t671\n1745\tDie Parteispitze zeigt sich offen für einen Konsens. Das würde die Richtigkeit des Atomausstiegs und des grünen Kurses besiegeln", sagt Steffi Lemke, politische Geschäftsführerin der Grünen.'
```

How can I fix this problem?

Please let me know If I need to provide further information.

**EDIT**
I tried @abby's suggestions. When I gave the full path, nothing changed, when I remove the delimeter and encoding parameters, I got the following erros:

```
pd.read_csv(trn_file,header=None)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 678, in parser_f
    return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
  File "anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 446, in _read
    data = parser.read(nrows)
  File "anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 1036, in read
    ret = self._engine.read(nrows)
  File "anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 1848, in read
    data = self._reader.read(nrows)
  File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 876, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.read
  File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 891, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._read_low_memory
  File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 945, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._read_rows
  File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 932, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._tokenize_rows
  File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 2112, in pandas._libs.parsers.raise_parser_error
pandas.errors.ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 11 fields in line 14, saw 12
```

Comment: 2 things, 1) try giving the full path of the file, 2) try removing the delimiter and encoding argument

Comment: @Abby I am going to try both now. However I wonder your intiution for the first option?

Comment: @Abby I edited my question after I tried your suggestions. They did not work unfortunatelly

Comment: What version of python are you using? You can pass `error_bad_lines=False` to skip those lines rather than error on them.

Comment: my python version is 3.6.5 . Thank you for your suggestion however, when I use delimiter `delimiter='\t'` I don't get any error. Besides, I have very limited data I prefer to fix these lines (somehow) rather than ignoring them

Comment: what is wondering me is why the script expects 11 fields and if the first lines already have 12

Comment: @nicksheen it expects 11 fields if I not set delimiter='\t' . Do you think it shouldn't do that even if I not set delimiter ?

Comment: Can yor try reading the csv with the `quoting = csv.QUOTE_NONE` parameter.

Comment: @Stef wauw, it seems you solved my problem. If you don't mind could you explain it now ? :)_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that some text entries contain quoting characters. They mask the delimiters and line feeds. By specifiying `quoting = csv.QUOTE_NONE` you can switch off this special treatment of quoting chars.
So use

```
pd_train = pd.read_csv(trn_file,delimiter='\t',encoding='utf-8',header=None,quoting = csv.QUOTE_NONE)
```

to read files with occasional quoting characters.
See https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html:

> csv.QUOTE_NONE
>
> Instructs writer objects to never quote fields. When the current delimiter occurs in output data it is preceded by the current
>   escapechar character. If escapechar is not set, the writer will raise
>   Error if any characters that require escaping are encountered.
>
> Instructs reader to perform no special processing of quote characters.

Answer (score 0):

```
pd.read_csv(”train.csv", quotechar='"',skipinitialspace=True)
quotechar=‘”’ --  Any commas between these characters shouldn’t be treated as new columns.

skipinitialspace=True --  Skip spaces after delimiter.
```